# How to implement new driver for GDAL in Debug mode

Tags: gdal, c++

I read the [GDAL's reference](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_drivertut.html) for driver implementation and write new driver, but only work in Release mode. So i need debug some parts of program but new driver don't add to GDAL driver's and when to open the file the returned dataset is NULL.

So, question is: How to implement new driver for GDAL in Debug mode?